# Can I delete my tmp/webalizer folder?

Tags: apache, apache-log-files

I've got a shared hosting plan with multiple site on my plan and I want to delete unneeded files. I estimate tmp/webalizer has around 10,000 files. Can I delete them all without any adverse effects?

- I don't mind losing the webalizer stats.
- This is a shared Hostgator server
- I'm asking about the tmp/webalizer folder in my hosting root,
  not the tmp folder I have under public_html.

If I could turn off webalizer, that would be helpful too.

Comment: Would you mind mentioning which provider you're using? That may help in knowing how to turn off webalizer.

Comment: @Coomie Is your hosting account using cPanel, or their own control panel? If it's cPanel, you should be able to just turn it off and then delete the contents of the `tmp/` folder. Their UI can be customized, but you might look for something like:  `Home » Server Configuration » Statistics Software Configuration`